# Change input element class on form_error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

So, i would like to change the style on a input element when i get a form_error on that element.

In my controller, i have all the form_validation rules, and every inputelement attributes

```
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        $data['username'] = array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'id' => 'username'
            );

        $data['password'] = array(
            'type' => 'password',
            'name' => 'password',
            'id' => 'password'
            );
    }
```

And in my View, i am printing them out.

```
            <li>
                <label for="username" class="bold">Username</label>
                <span class="input-prepend">$</span>
                <?php echo form_input($username); ?>
            </li>
```

So, i need the easiset way to change the class on the corrisponding element that gets a form error. Is it any easy way to do this?

Please, let me know if i'm explaining bad :)
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this...

```
<li<?php echo (form_error('username') == '') ? '' : ' class="yes_error"'; ?>>
    <label for="username" class="bold">Username</label>
    <span class="input-prepend">$</span>
    <?php echo form_input($username); ?>
</li>
```

Output if there is error in username

```
<li class="yes_error">
    <label for="username" class="bold">Username</label>
    <span class="input-prepend">$</span>
    ....
</li>
```

And style it...

```
.yes_error {
    color: #FF0000;
    background: ...
    .....
}
```

Comment: Just a quick question; Is this the easiest way to do it? Let's say that i have 10 input elements. Do i have to write 10 if-clauses then?
Or maybe create a function?

Comment: Yes, you can create a helper function `check_error($error_data) { if(empty($error_data) { return; } else { return ' class="yes_error"'; } }` and in form view you can do like this `<li<?php echo check_error(form_error('username')); ?>></li>`. But it is not much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo form_input($username, '', 'HERE your Css styles like style="" and javascript'); ?>
```

Why you not look the manual? http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html